# how to notify java desktop clients about changes from server?

Tags: java, desktop, notify

I would like to develop a desktop application with Java (I've got very basic knowledge of Java). It'll run on the client's computer and will pull information from the server hosted in the internet. I can set a schedule task to connect to the server every 2minutes and check for any update/changes but I don't think it's a very good idea. Is there any way to let the clients know about the changes? For example, when every there would a change server will send a notification to the clients to update? The server might a different technology e.g. Java

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Pushing *to* clients is always going to be hard - largely because of firewalls. Making the client pull from the server (with HTTP) is much more likely to work in most situations.

Now, you're currently polling every two minutes. That *may* be appropriate - or it may be better to do it much more rarely (once a day, say) depending on what you're updating. If it's updates to the client software, rare updates are fine. If it's updates to a chat conversation, even two minutes is far too long - in which case you should look into [comet / long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) as a technique. (There are various technologies for implementing long polling; you don't have to use anything specific - that's why I described it as a technique rather than anything else.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMS to send messages from your server to your applications if you use a Java Server.

Or you could use a Comet application to push messages to the clients via HTTP.

A third way would be to create your own push system where your clients connect to the server to give some informations on how to be contacted, and with the Observer/Observable pattern you notify every client at each modification.

---

**Resources :**

- [Oracle.com - JMS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-142945.html)
- [Wikipedia - Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))
- [Wikipedia - Publish/Suscribe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe)