# Server side events with desktop client .i.e no browser (java)

Tags: java, spring, redis, push-notification, desktop-application

We are in the need of "push notification" mechanism, to desktop clients written in java, and mobile clients such as android, ios and windowsphone8. I came across "server side events" which fits very well, as we only need unidirectional communication from the server to the clients, so websockets are overkill for this scenario. We are currently using polling as fallback but we want to avoid this as much as possible.

As I understand it the server needs to be some kind of "publish subscribe" module but I'm not sure if "spring framework" provides any helping hand here or if there are other frameworks helping out with the pipelining. I have read about redis being a good candidate for publish subscribe  module. **However what framework / component to use to connected a java desktop client to this publish subscribe module is what I want help with.**

There are a bunch of technologies / framework out there html 5 websockets, socket.io and so on but these only work for web, i.e browser clients..   I'm looking at java.net.ServerSockets (not used it before) but **slightly unsure if that is the best approach**. We will have a seperate "service module" running on the same desktop as the java desktop client, This service will handle a push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use Java Messaging Service (JMS)

**Spring's support for JMS**

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

**J2EE JMS**

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/overview.html#1027335

Also, check out these similar questions --

[how to notify java desktop clients about changes from server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671998/how-to-notify-java-desktop-clients-about-changes-from-server)

[Push notifications to various devices through a common code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400533/push-notifications-to-various-devices-through-a-common-code)

Comment: My experience with JMS is limited. Our clients are located on users local computer around the world, and the servers are distributed in a private cloud. Can you still use the JMS service, how many ports do you need to open. The firewall on users computer might be blocking several ports and we want to minimize the firewall preconfig as much as possible and try to use port 80 or 443 or similar. This is why something like server side events but for non browser clients would have been great. But again I'm wondering how googles push notification work, do they use jms?